# Xcode variable debug inspector not working properly

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

No matter what I do, Xcode (bottom left below the editor) shows the value of `self` and my first variable in the unit I am trying to debug or step through instead of the variables I want to inspect.

What I have tried:

- Restarted xcode
- Clean + rebuild
- Hover mouse over variable, click the down arrow (it seems like Xcode does not grab my click correctly, sort of hard to explain)

No tooltip is shown either when I hover over a variable. (I have tried to click the edior first to ensure it has focus.)

Answer (score 0):

in the bottom left of the debug window, where it probably says `Auto` set that to all variables, registers... etc and see if it shows you what you are looking for, otherwise post a picture of what is happening